# Why is this done with linked lists in C ++? (handling them like stack)

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int valor;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

// Lista enlazada "simple", manipulandola con el metodo LIFO (pila).

void agregar_nodo(Nodo *&cima, int n);  // ¿Puntero por referencia?

int main(){
    Nodo *cima = NULL;
    agregar_nodo(cima, 2);
    agregar_nodo(cima, 4);

    return 0;
}

void agregar_nodo(Nodo *&cima, int n){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo(); // (struct Nodo) | Nodo() Se puede usar cualquier sintaxis
    nuevo_nodo->valor = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = cima;
    cima = nuevo_nodo;
}
```

After hours of research I managed to understand the logic of the code (it is not mine, it is from a course that I follow). However, there are three doubts that I could not clear during said investigation, which are:

1. Why use new?
   I mean, I think there is no need to use it, why use it in this case?
   Can the previous code be done without the new? In that case, how would it be?
2. What happened to the delete?
   I understand that in c ++, each time we use the new operator, we must then put its respective delete. Why in this case does not have?
3. Why pass the pointer by reference? (first parameter of the function "agregar_nodo")

> This is the most curious of all because I understand that in C, the
> references are made with pointers, but in C ++ we can do it
> both with pointers and with the unary operator.

With that clear, I don't see the point in passing a pointer with the unary operator together, knowing that it isn't necessary. It is assumed that using this only with the pointer will be passed as a reference (although the function makes a copy as always, being a pointer we will have with us the original memory address, that is, the one that was outside the function.)

So why use the two together?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. If you do not dynamically allocate this node and instead automatically allocate it, what happens to the node when the function exits?. If you statically allocate the node to get around the problem raised automatically allocating it, how many nodes can you have?

Comment: In 2020 the main reason to use English identifiers is to get answers on SO ;-).

Comment: 2. Think on when you want to delete the node. What would happen if you deleted the node after adding it but before removing it?

Comment: The reason for passing the root (or, in Portugese, top) of the list by reference is *so that it also changes on the caller side* (main's `cima` points to the new node after `agregar_nodo´ returns). In C one would pass the address of the pointer.

Comment: 3. This one is a bit odd. But remember that a pointer is just another variable, but a variable that happens to contain the location of another object. If you pass an variable by value, you get a copy.  If you pass a pointer by value, you still get a copy of the pointer.  If you change where the copy points inside the function, the original won't know.

Comment: @user4581301 Do you say that in C the reference is made with **?

Comment: @Retr0 Yes. In C pointer-to-pointer would be the most direct and reasonable way to pass the pointer by reference.

Comment: A couple of things, can you please write your code in english , and send it stackOverflow is an english community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to questions:

1. If you didn't use `new` then where would your `Nodo` objects live? They would have to be locals on the stack, or globals. If they're locals, then they'll disappear as soon as the function that declares them exits. If they're globals, you'll only have a certain number of them to use, however many you declared. If you want to extend the linked list every time someone calls `agregar_nodo` then you have to allocate a new `Nodo` on the heap with `new` each time.
2. The program is an example that is showing you how to add elements to a linked list. There's no code to *remove* anything from the linked list, which is where `delete` would be used.
3. The code is adding new elements to the front of a linked list. Each time it adds a new element to the front, it has to update the "start of the list" or "head" pointer to point to the new first element. The head pointer is (obviously) a pointer, and `agregar_nodo` has to update it, so it's passed in as a reference to a pointer. Sometimes programs use a pointer to pointer instead (so it would be `Nodo **cima`).

The last one is a little tricky. If the function was declared this way, without the reference:

```
void agregar_nodo(Nodo *cima, int n)
```

then it would still *compile*, however, when you ran it, the last line `cima = nuevo_nodo` would update the local variable `cima`, not the one in the `main` function. So after the first time you called the function, `cima` in `main` would still be `NULL`. So the function instead accepts it by reference so the function can update `cima` in `main`.